# Cannot delete row in table by Google Docs API

Tags: c#, api, documentation, delete-row

I used Google docs to tried to delete some rows in table by use DeleteTableRowRequest but I met exception with specify TableStartLocation property. My code is below:

```
public static void DeleteRequestGDocs(List<Request> requestsList, int? index2Del)
        {
            Request request = new Request();
            Location tableLocation = new Location();
            tableLocation.SegmentId = string.Empty;
            tableLocation.Index = 11;

            TableCellLocation tableCellLocationDel = new TableCellLocation();
            tableCellLocationDel.RowIndex = index2Del;
            tableCellLocationDel.ColumnIndex = 0;
            tableCellLocationDel.TableStartLocation = tableLocation;

            DeleteTableRowRequest delRequest = new DeleteTableRowRequest();
            delRequest.TableCellLocation = tableCellLocationDel;
            request.DeleteTableRow = delRequest;

            requestsList.Add(request);
        }
```

Please help me

Update 1: When program exetute to delete. I met error "Invalid requests[0].deleteTableRow: Invalid table start location. Must specify the start index of the table." with code below

```
var bodyDelete = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest();
                    bodyDelete.Requests = requestsDeleteList;
                    var batchDeleteRequest = docsService.Documents.BatchUpdate(bodyDelete, mergedFile.Id);
                    var resultDelete = await batchDeleteRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: What did the exception say?

Comment: Exception said that "Invalid requests[0].deleteTableRow: Invalid table start location. Must specify the start index of the table."

Comment: Hello @MouseOnMars, Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that `tableStartLocation` in your request matches the value of `startIndex` for the table you are trying to access in the document you are editing.

The corresponding part of the document JSON with the `startIndex` should look like the following:

```
      {
        "startIndex": 12,
        "endIndex": 23,
        "table": {...}
      },
```

See related issue in google tracker here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158124540